# Reporting services stored procedures

Tags: reporting-services

I have been working  on a script that will swap two IDs round which are primary keys:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ID 
    @OldName NVARCHAR(128), 
    @NewName NVARCHAR(128)
AS
    DECLARE @NewId INT, @OldId INT

    CREATE TABLE TmpTable (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(128)) 

    INSERT INTO TmpTable (Name,ID) 
    VALUES (@NewName, (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @NewName));

    INSERT INTO TmpTable (Name,ID)
    VALUES(@OldName, (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @OldName))

    UPDATE Table1 
    SET ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1000 FROM Table1) 
    WHERE [NAME] = @NewName

    UPDATE Table1 
    SET ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) + 2000 FROM Table1) 
    WHERE [NAME] = @OldName

    UPDATE Table1 
    SET ID = (SELECT ID FROM TmpTable WHERE Name = @NewName)
    WHERE [Name] = @OldName

    UPDATE Table1 
    SET ID = (SELECT ID FROM TmpTable WHERE Name = @OldName) 
    WHERE [Name] = @NewName

    DROP TABLE TmpTable
go
```

What I am now trying to do is to run this as a report in reporting services where the NewNAme and OldNAme will be selected from a drop down box that queries the Table1 Table. At present when I try to import this code it asks for the values.

1. How do I import a stored procedure into a report.
2. How do I get a dropdown box to query the column [Name].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using the Report wizard most of the time, using text to import the stored procedure like

```
exec ID 1,2
```

That gets me that base return values for the tablix. However in your case that does not apply as there is no select return.

After the wizard creates the report, right click on the dataset and select the stored proc. Click Refresh Fields and the parameters will be added automagically.

To get your report parameters to be drop downs you need a data source for them. I add a new dataset based on either a select statement or another stored proc to select the values I need.

Right click on the parameter and select Parameter Properties
You can now jump to the available values tab and choose "Get values from a query"
Select the dataset that provides the drop down values.

There are other options like allowing nulls etc that can fine tune how the drop down works.

Pretty curious why you would want a report that runs the SQL you show without returning any values. Seems there would be better ways to give the user the power to run something like that.

Answer (score 1):

when you add a stored procedure to your report ass data source, the ssrs automatically add its parameters to report ass report parameter.

if you want to specify the parameters by drop down, you must write an application like a web application and pass this parameters to your report.